# Read output of a tcp packet sent with /dev/tcp/?

Tags: networking, bash, tcp

I send the output of the "ls" from host1 to host2 with this command:

```
ls >/dev/tcp/<host2_IP>/<host2_port>
```

But I would like to find a way to directly see the output of this "ls" command on host 2.

Any idea how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use netcat to listen on the port you specified

```
nc -l 3333
```

(I've used port 3333 as an example)